# Searching similar products sku with sphinxsearch

Tags: search, kohana, sphinx

I have search form in my e-commerce site. Search engine is Sphinxsearch.

I have products with sku like (04078, PS04078, DS04078, 04078-1, 04078-2, 4078-3).

---

The problem I cannot figure out how to configure sphinx to get results I need:

Searching by '04078' gives me only item with sku 04078, but not all 6 items.

**How to get all 6 items in result set?**

My conf:

```
source products
{
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = #
        sql_user                = #
        sql_pass                = #
        sql_db                  = #
        sql_port                = # 
        sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8
        sql_query               = \
                SELECT id,price,name,sku,producer_name \
                                        FROM products
        #sql_attr_string         = post_title
        #sql_field_string        = post_content
        sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id

}

index products
{
        source                  = products
        path                    = /var/data/products
        docinfo                 = extern
        mlock                   = 0
        charset_type = utf-8
        html_strip = 1
        html_remove_elements = style, script
        enable_star = 1
        min_word_len = 1
        min_infix_len = 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new regex filter in 2.1.1 beta sounds just the ticket to munge the product codes into a consistant form...

http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/sphinx.html#conf-regexp-filter